# canvas does not draw with audio tag using HTML5

Tags: html, audio, canvas

my code was working fine and good. it calls javascript scripts on the html page which draws on the page and makes animations. now, what i have done now is to add the  tag in order to play an audio clip automatically. the problem i have is that my animations stop drawing, but there is music playing in the background.

below is the index.html that i use to run on. it is the only html file in the project.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html class="no-js" lang="en" manifest="./main.manifest">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <title> My Game </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="SweetPotatoes">

        <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,
        initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/game.css">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">


    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="container">
            <canvas id="canvasSausage" display="block" ></canvas>
        </div>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"><\/script>')
        </script>




<!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->

            <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/libs/require.1.0.8.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/libs/Draw.js"></script>
            <script src="js/libs/Smile.js"></script>
            <script src="js/libs/UpDpwn.js"></script>
            <script src="js/mylibs/SmellyCanvas/core/canvasMain.js"></script>

            <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
            <script defer src="js/plugins.js"></script>
            <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>

            <!-- end scripts-->

            <script>
                window._gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UAXXXXXXXX1'], ['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageLoadTime']];
                Modernizr.load({
                    load : ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
                });
            </script>

            <!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you want to support IE 6.
            chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
            <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
            <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
            <![endif]-->
            <audio autoplay="true">
            <source src="sound/Heart.mp3"></source>
                audio tag not supported.
            </audio>

        </body>
    </html>
```

my main.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2012-08-11

index.html
sound/Heart.mp3
```

Comment: are you getting seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: i removed manifest="./main.manifest" and it worked fine...any ideas why?

Comment: your manifest file could be erroring... open it in chrome and watch the files download with the manifest included and see if you see any errors

Comment: can i place a dropbox link in the manifest? i was using a URI path to a file in the project, maybe that's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use manifest while you are developing.
Manifest is like browser-caching on steroids.
There are enough problems with making changes to external .js files and then having the browser not grab them, because you're using versions the browser saved from previous visits (when something was broken/different).

With a manifest, you're pretty much extending that caching ability to eternity, unless you're going to write scripts to manage the manifest.
In a word: don't.

Build what you're going to build, and when it's done -- at least, when it's at a 1.0 phase, or a good, solid, public-beta...

...then start thinking about caching files for eternity in the manifest.

Comment: Norguard, if i understand you correct...i should be placing some contraints or conditions when caching say when detect connection is lost, or when game first load. because looking back, apparently, thats what i didnt do..

Comment: What I mean is if you are currently developing your game / page, and making changes and bouncing back and forth between editing and viewing, a manifest can cause huge problems in that regard, because if those files exist on the page already, and your manifest is set to cache for any useful period of time, then you're going to have to invalidate your cache if you want to see those changes.  Manifests are for when you've got your finished product, and you want the user's browser to store all of the data as-is, for as long as possible...  ...which doesn't help devs to revise, refresh and review.

Comment: ahhh, Norguard that really clear things up. i'll probably do the manifest and caching at the end now since the game is pretty much done. can you upvote my question so i can accept your question, thanks!